# How can I monitor the users that are connected to my ad hoc wifi network?

Tags: wifi, ad-hoc

I'd just like to see who is connecting to my computers Access Point wifi.

I'm sharing Internet from Ethernet to wifi with a password, etc.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's not ad hoc, it's an Access Point.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following to list all connections on your Mac through all interfaces.

```
arp -a
```

To limit to a single interface, use:

```
arp -a -i en1
```

Comment: thanks! this is a cool command. It just displays MAC addresses though, correct? I guess I was hoping for a GUI that could display device names or something more robust, like an admin tool.

Comment: @pinhead It shows IP addresses and hostnames too, but yes, there's no 'admin tool' of such.

Answer (score 1):

There is a GUI solution on Apple Store--it is FREE !

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/who-is-on-my-wifi/id909760813?mt=12

Who Is On My WiFi
By IO3O LLC

> Who's On My Wifi is an easy way to Detect Unknown Devices on your
>   network.
>
> Whether it's someone using your wired or wireless network, Who's On My
>   Wifi's optional automated background scanning will find all devices on
>   the network, let you tag them, and notify you if any new unknown
>   devices are found.

Sample:

[image: who is on my network]

Answer (score 0):

Non-free GUI-solutions are [iNet](http://www.inetapp.de/en/inetx.html) and [Network Radar](http://www.mac-attender.com/networkradar/).
Network Radar provides a [free trial](http://mac-attender.com/downloads/networkradar/NetworkRadar.zip).